# In the iOS SDK, does TCDevice updateCapabilityToken: ever not crash the app?

Tags: ios, twilio

Every time I call `[phone updateCapabilityToken:newCapabilityToken]`, my app crashes. The stack trace it gives isn't very informative. The docs don't say much about this method. Is there something I need to know about when its ok to call this method?

Also, deleting a TCDevice and then making a new one isn't a good alternative since that seems to always crash the program as well.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing a similar issue, except it's happening intermittently on `initWithCapabilityToken:delegate:`.

Comment: Not yet unfortunately.

Comment: You may want to pull or aim your podfile at the latest version of the Twilio SDK v1.2.2 (updated 1/29/2015). This seems to have fixed our intermittent crashing issue.

Comment: Thank you @LeeFastenau! Seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to pull or aim your podfile at the latest version of the Twilio SDK v1.2.2 (updated 1/29/2015). This seems to have fixed our intermittent crashing issue.